# Wireless Card Restart on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04

I want to restart the network service in Ubuntu 18.04. I tried `/etc/init.d/networking restart` but the command didn't come out as expected. Can someone help resolve my issue?

Comment: `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` should restart the network.

Comment: another way is `sudo service network-manager restart`. This must get the job done

Comment: Since Ubuntu 18.04 still uses `systemd` you should get out of the habit of using `upstart` files like init.d files and also stop using `sudo service` and should start using `systemctl` instead.  See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-upstart-and-systemd

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

To restart the PCI Wi-Fi card, open up Terminal and type `sudo su`. Enter your password and press enter. Then, type `/etc/init.d/network-manager restart`. The wireless card should be finished restarting and idle.

### Option 2

The second option to restart the PCI Wi-Fi card, type `sudo su` and type your password finishing with an enter. Then, type service networking restart or service network-manager restart (I recommend network-manager) and the wireless card is restarted.